# File not found when executing a .exe from PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a script which contains several libraries, one of which is iapws.
When I create an executable using
`pyinstaller --onefile myScript.spec`
I get the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Miguel\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI147002\iapws\VERSION

I tried upgrading all my libraries and using `hiddenimports=['iapws']` on the spec file
As far as I understand, the problem is that the necessary files are not being extracted into the temp folder when executing the file.
Any workaround for this?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to force pyinstaller to include iapws files, as it seems to have issues generating the appropriate hooks. This worked for me:

```
pyinstaller "your_script.py" --collect-all iapws
```

I reviewed command options here which helped:
https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html

Comment: God bless you, your answer came just in time. Many thanks!